Name of TV series where folks jumped from one magic gate to another on Island in Bermuda Triangle
When I was a child in the 70s (maybe 80s but I think 70s), I saw a sci-fi/fantasy tv series about a group (perhaps a family?) that was on an island in the Bermuda triangle.  Each week, they'd go through some sort of gate that was a time portal or barrier and end up in another land.   For example, one week they might be in "pirate land", the next week, "roman land", etc.  I'm very vague on the details because I was young.  About all I remember for sure is that they were somewhere in the Bermuda Triangle and the type of land/culture they were in changed each week.  Anyone know the series?

Sounds like The Fantastic Journey from 1977:

The series concerns a family and their associates who charter a boat out into the Caribbean for a scientific expedition. After an encounter in the area of the Bermuda Triangle with an unnatural green cloud the group find themselves shipwrecked on a mysterious uncharted island from which they are unable to escape. [...] they have been caught in a space/time continuum where people from the past, present, future and from other worlds are trapped, co-existing on the island in a series of timezones. [...] The only way to travel between timezones is via invisible gateways which instantaneously transport individuals or groups from one zone to another.





That's it!  Thanks!  Bonus question:  Where can I view the episodes?
